# Vba loop to open multiple text files in one folder on one excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am having trouble with a vba loop to import 21 text files that I have into one excel sheet. 
I found this on here but I keep getting an error code.I want the vba to loop through one folder, copy and paste to master file one column apart with the file above the data set.

```
Sub combine()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim ExcelApp As Object
    Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    ExcelApp.Visible = False
    ExcelApp.ScreenUpdating = False
    ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    ExcelApp.EnableEvents = False

    '**VARIABLES**
    Dim folderPath As String
    folderPath = "Y:\plan_graphs\final\mich_alco_test\files\"

    'COUNT THE FILES
    Dim totalFiles As Long
    totalFiles = 0
    Dim fileTitle As String
    fileTitle = Dir(folderPath & "*.xl??")
    Do While fileTitle <> ""
    totalFiles = totalFiles + 1
    fileTitle = Dir()
    Loop

    'OPENING FILES
    Dim resultWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim dataWorkbook As Workbook
    Set resultWorkbook = ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Open("Y:\plan_graphs\final\mich_alco_test\result.xlsx")


    fileTitle = Dir(folderPath & "*.xl??")

    'FOR EACH FILE
    Do While fileTitle <> ""
        Set dataWorkbook = ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & fileTitle)
        dataWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Range("A1").Select
        dataWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Selection.CurrentRegion.Select


         `resultWorkbook.Range
         fileTitle = Dir()
     Loop

    ExcelApp.Quit
    Set ExcelApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thank you.

Comment: Which one is the error you are getting?

Comment: "but I keep getting an error code" -this is not a very useful description of the actual  problem you're having.  Always helps to provide the error message and the line where it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Sub combine()

    Const FOLDER_PATH As String = "Y:\plan_graphs\final\mich_alco_test\"

    Dim resultWorkbook As Workbook, fileTitle, i as long
    Dim dataWorkbook As Workbook
    Set resultWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(FOLDER_PATH & "result.xlsx")

    i = 0 
    fileTitle = Dir(FOLDER_PATH & "files\*.xl??")

    Do While fileTitle <> ""
        i = i + 1 
        With Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "files\" & fileTitle)
            .Worksheets("List1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy _
               resultWorkbook.Sheets("data").Cells(2,i)
            .Close False 'don't save
        End With
        resultWorkbook.Sheets("data").Cells(1, i).Value = fileTitle 
        fileTitle = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub
```

If you're already in Excel there's no need to create a new instance to do this.

Comment: I tried using this code i kept getting a 1004 error after replacing the folder path with mine.